# Web Standard for naming conventions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to know if there are any web standards or professional ways for naming conventions in a project. Is there any standards for css and js ?

**CSS**

- style.css
- main.css
- base.css
- base.css

JS files

- script.js
- index.js

Comment: No, it's just a primarily opinion based. Just use the best that fits with your requirements and your workflow. Doesn't matter the name of the files, but it's better if there are a coherence. This should be closed as primarily opinion based.

Comment: Every company has its own standards, and it depends on application and its size how you structure your css/js files. In fact in most cases you will bundle it anyway and you end up with one js/css file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your provided file name is valid.
You must name your file to represent it's content:

What can I say from file name:
`scripts.js` - All scripts, not minimized
`index.js` - Only scripts that will be used in index file.
`style.css` - All styles for page
`main.css` - Main set of styles that will be used on page, missing specific parts
`base.css` - Same as `main.css`

You have to select name that fits best.